# Tool to visualize cloud architectures

Tags: architecture, cloud, visualization

Is there a good tool to draw diagramms of cloud architectures?

I know pen and paper is a good way, but I need something to use in an article, so the output should look professional and well rendered.

An example can be found here: http://aws.amazon.com/solutions/case-studies/photowall/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any good diagramming application will let you do this. [Microsoft Visio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visio) is a good example. [Open Office Draw](http://www.openoffice.org/product/draw.html) might also do the trick, although I cannot speak from experience.